# I18n::InvalidLocale Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am creating a multilingual app and I want to make the app switch to the language of the visitors browser language settings. I have noticed that it works perfectly if the language settings matches one of the available locales. But unfortunately as soon as the browser language does not match one of the locales I will get an I18n::InvalidLocale Error... ("es" is not a valid locale) eventhough I set up an default locale...

**What am I missing?
How can I make this work? Any hints?**

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Testapp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

**In my locales I have de.yml, en.yml and a devise.en.yml file.**

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/ do

    root 'welcomes#index'
    devise_for :users
    get "language" => "welcomes#language"

    get "welcomes/download_pdf"

    resources :welcomes do
      get :download, on: :member
    end

    resources :resumes do
      get :download, on: :member
    end

    get '*path' => redirect('/')

  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p><%= link_to "EN", root_path(locale: 'en') %></p>
<p><%= link_to "DE", root_path(locale: 'de') %></p>
```

**UPDATE**

I have noticed when I run the rails console and check the I18n.available_locales it gives me [:en, :fr, :"zh-CN", :"zh-TW", :de] very strange?! Because I have not set those locales and I have not those in my apps are those settings the default settings? So I guess the config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en] settings is necessary.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that if use: config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
No translations are working but I will not get an error. If I update addtionally on environments/development.rb: config.i18n.fallbacks = true
Then only the default value is shown in my case english but I can not change it to german.

Answer (score 1):

`config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true`
This might be overriding the default locale behavior. Try Turning it off so the default locale can kick in.
And provide a whitelist of available locales like this:
`config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]`

**Edit**
Try doing this in your application controller:

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Comment: If I change that then I'm not getting an error but it won't translate anything because it will not access the locales. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try add a whitelist of available locales: `config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]`

Comment: Edit the answer again. Try this one.

Comment: Nope it still does not work... it raises the error on:     I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale

I don't see anything wrong with that code :/

Comment: What's the error? can you copy the error and stack trace

Comment: Why don't you set the local in the url rather than a header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153033/discussion-between-sarmad-sabih-and-trickydiddy).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  available_locales = {'de' => 'de', 'en' => 'en'}
  available_locales[request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first]
end
```

Comment: Error is gone but it will only be the default language in my case english... and I will not be able to switch languages.. thanks for trying!

Comment: I have changed answer, try using hash like this it accepts both strings and literals as keys.

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue persists... the error is gone but it will only be the default language... im not able to switch languages which does not make any sense... very weird... :/ Thanks for your patience!

Comment: How exactly you changes locale?

Comment: Check my edited Question.. Im using routes using a path scope.
With a simple link_to helper method to switch between languages...
www. example.com/en/...
www. example.com/de/...

Comment: I think you need to change locale in index action and use passed in params one. And store locale in session for example.

Comment: Why? It works if the visitor has the the same language settings as my locales... the issue is that the I18n gem does not switch to the default value when there is no certain locales... And I dont have no idea why... :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the locale via the `locale` placeholder in the routes, in your `application.rb` you should also resolve it using the value of `params[:locale]` not the header. So in `application.rb` the set_locale should be

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

See the section on setting locale from URL params here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this as the before_action in the application controller.

```
  def set_locale
    browser_locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header.to_sym
    if I18n.available_locales.include?(browser_locale)
      I18n.locale = browser_locale
    else
      I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
```

Then it should only try to set the locale if its available.